# Pull all functions from a module that contain a common attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, colorama

I'm looking to pull all the color [eg LIGHTMAGENTA_EX, YELLOW...] functions (or whatever the appropriate term is) inside the Fore (or Back) module of colorama, and append them to a list. I know I can append *all* the functions with

```
from colorama import Fore
colors = []
for item in dir(Fore):
    colors.append(item)
```

but I only want the ones that describe colors. I have noticed a common attribute about these functions: they have a property 'AnsiFore'. Is it possible to create a list of these functions without manually doing so?

Comment: try `if type(item) == AnsiFore: colors.append(item)`. You probably need to import AnsiFore from colorama

Comment: @MEE unfortunately the type returns string for all items.
Brad, I'm running 3.6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colors within `Fore` are not `AnsiFore` objects, as you said in your question.  They're just strings, so they also don't have an `AnsiFore` property.

```
>>> dir(Fore)
['BLACK', 'BLUE', 'CYAN', 'GREEN', 'LIGHTBLACK_EX', 'LIGHTBLUE_EX', 'LIGHTCYAN_EX', 'LIGHTGREEN_EX', 'LIGHTMAGENTA_EX', 'LIGHTRED_EX', 'LIGHTWHITE_EX', 'LIGHTYELLOW_EX', 'MAGENTA', 'RED', 'RESET', 'WHITE', 'YELLOW', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

The best you can probably do here is:

```
>>> colors = [i for i in dir(Fore) if not i.startswith('_')]
>>> colors
['BLACK',
 'BLUE',
 'CYAN',
 'GREEN',
 'LIGHTBLACK_EX',
 'LIGHTBLUE_EX',
 'LIGHTCYAN_EX',
 'LIGHTGREEN_EX',
 'LIGHTMAGENTA_EX',
 'LIGHTRED_EX',
 'LIGHTWHITE_EX',
 'LIGHTYELLOW_EX',
 'MAGENTA',
 'RED',
 'RESET',
 'WHITE',
 'YELLOW']
```

If you want, have a look at the module [source](https://github.com/tartley/colorama/blob/master/colorama/ansi.py).  The colors are strings created by:

- A number (`Black = 30`)
- Taking the `str` representation of this `int`, prepending it with `'\033['`, and appending `m` to it:

I.e.:

```
>>> BLACK = 10

>>> CSI = '\033['
... 

>>> def code_to_chars(code):
...     return CSI + str(code) + 'm'
... 

>>> code_to_chars(BLACK)
'\x1b[10m'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well enough.  Can you help me understand why there is an 'AnsiFore' property next to certain strings when I call Fore [like this](https://imgur.com/a/j62pz)?

Comment: Hm, what IDE is that @D.Rad?

Comment: Seems to be telling you the type of `Fore` itself: `type(Fore)` --> `colorama.ansi.AnsiFore`